# How to auto reload spring boot application in docker using spring dev tools

Tags: intellij-idea, docker, spring-boot

I followed this [link](https://medium.com/@lhartikk/development-environment-in-spring-boot-with-docker-734ad6c50b34#.e15x9f5ry) to deploy my application into local docker directly and debug it.
I was able to deploy and debug but auto reload was not working for me
Can you help me with auto reload for dockers using spring dev tools

The reason I am interested in doing it this way because my application talks to 5 different services and running them individually might be little difficult. So will be hosting them individually on the docker.

My trouble here is as of now I have to kill the container, then remove it and then add the new one back and I have to do this each time I change something

I am using Spring Boot 1.4 | IntelliJ | Docker and spring dev tools

Answer (score 4):

You should add new Run/Debug configuration and select **RemoteSpringApplication** as a Main class. Also you should set **Program arguments** as ip address to your service (ex. http://localhost:8080). Also add **spring.devtools.remote.secret: mysecret** into your application properties.
My configuration:
[image]

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#_running_the_remote_client_application

Spring boot has bug with RemoteSpringApplication which do not allows to remove or add new class. This will be fixed in Spring Boot 1.4.3
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7379

Comment: Also review this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759587/intellij-spring-dev-tools-remote-docker-error-unexpected-404-response-uploadi/47425443#47425443

Answer (score 4):

Also, try to add this plugin:

`./pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```